# Trying to get property of non-object (showing user profile)

Tags: laravel

```
public function getEdit(){
    $user = User::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return View::make(Users.edit')->with('user', $user);
}
```

VIEW CODE

```
<table class= "bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>username</td><td>{{$user->username}}</td></tr>
        <td>username</td><td>{{$user->email}}</td></tr>
        <td>username</td><td>{{$user->password }}</td></tr>
        <td>username</td><td>{{$user->updated_at}}</td></tr>
        <td>username</td><td>{{$user->created_at}}</td>
    </tr>
<Table>
```

Comment: Is the user is logged in when you are calling `Auth::user()->id`?

Comment: Initially no but now I have logged in and the errorException shifted to the views am sending the views code

Comment: Show the code of `view`.

Comment: ErrorException :undefined variable:user

Comment: Just sent the view code

Comment: `Auth::user()` should already contain the user object. You don't need to retrieve it again from your `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this when the user is logged in:

```
public function getEdit(){
    if(!Auth::check()) return false; // or throw an exception
    return View::make(Users.edit')->with('user', Auth::user());
}
```

Also this will work (For example):

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

The `get()` returns a collection even if there is only one model in the collection so `$user->username` is not working because `$user` is a `collection` object.